# Problem in Understanding the Concept of Significant Figures in Numerical Mathematical Analysis

Tags: numerical-methods, definition, significant-figures

I was reading about the term, "*Significant*" digits in the book, "Numerical Mathematical Analysis " by J Scarborough.

> The definition of the significant digits were given as:
>
> A significant figure is any one of the digits $1, 2,3,... 9;$ and $0$ is a significant figure except when it is used to fix the decimal point or to fill the places of unknown or discarded digits.
>
> Thus, in the number $0. 00263$ the significant figures are $2, 6, 3;$ the zeros are used merely to fix the decimal point and are therefore not significant. In the number $3809,$ however, all the digits, including the zero, are significant figures. In a number like $46300$ there is nothing in the number as written to
> show whether or not the zeros are significant figures. The ambiguity
> can be removed by writing the number in one of the forms $4.63\times10^4$
> $4.630 \times10^4$, or $4.6300\times10^4$, the number of significant figures being
> indicated by the factor at the left.

---

If my understanding is correct, it means that say, there is a number $7878$ and it's written as $7800$ instead of $7878$ then, the number of significant digits in $7800$ is $2$ and they are $7$ and $8.$ The two zeros in $7800$ are ignored as they were used *to fill the places of unknown or discarded digits, which were $7$ and $8$ in this case.*
**(Is this a  valid reasoning?)**

Next, in the part, where it's written,

> In a number like $46300$ there is nothing in the number as written to
> show whether or not the zeros are significant figures.

I think they called the number ambiguous as, $4,6,3$ are significant digits and the confusion is with the two zeros appended at the end.

The last two zeros in $46300$ are significant digits if $46300$ is equivalent to $46300.00$ or if, $46300$ is written in place of some number say, $46398$ (, i.e the last two digits in $46398$ which are $9$ and $8$ are discarded or is unknown and instead of it, we write, $46300$). But we aren't sure of whether any of the above two scenarios are taking place or not.
**(Is this inference correct?)**

If this inference is correct then, why does they write,

> The ambiguity can be removed by writing the number in one of the forms $4.63\times10^4$ $4.630 \times10^4$, or $4.6300\times10^4$, the number of significant figures being indicated by the factor at the left.

I don't understand how the ambiguity gets removed. Also, what's the number of significant digits in $4.63\times10^4$ $4.630 \times10^4$, or $4.6300\times10^4$. I have no idea about what it is ?

Comment: In $46300$, we don't know if the $0$s are significant or if one or both of them are there just to "fix the decimal point". Written as $46300$, we don't know if there are $3$, $4$, or $5$ significant digits. However, if written as $4.63\times10^4$, we know there are only $3$ significant digits. Written as $4.630\times10^4$, we know that there are $4$ significant digits. Finally, written as $4.6300\times10^4$, we know that there are $5$ significant digits. In the last three examples, the trailing $0$s are not there to fix the decimal point.

Comment: As for the distinction between those cases, in $4.63 \cdot 10^4$, you can think of all digits smaller than the hundreds place of the whole number as being uncertain. In $4.630 \cdot 10^4$, the tens place is pinned down but the ones place is still uncertain. And so forth.

Comment: @robjohn Ok, but are my understanding and inferences mentioned in OP correct?

Comment: Note that you can also write $46300.$ to imply all the zeroes are significant, though scientific notation is the only way to convey that only one of the zeroes is significant.

Comment: Well, if the number is written as $7800$, you don't know what the original number was. There is no way to tell that the original number was $7878$ (which should be rounded to $7900$).

Comment: @robjohn That was just an example. Surely, if in $7878$ we were not aware of the last two digits then we would have represented it my $7800$. Isn't it?

Comment: A number with a given number of significant figures usually comes from data that has more digits, but a limited accuracy, so it is rounded. For example, $7803.276\pm4.21$, where $4.21$ indicates a range of precision for the measurement. This could be written as $7800$, intending $3$ significant figures. However, written this way, as mentioned in the question, we don't know whether there are $2$, $3$, or $4$ significant digits.

Answer (score 2):

A number with a given number of significant figures usually comes from data that has more digits, but a limited accuracy, so it is rounded. For example, $46303.276\pm4.21$, where $4.21$ indicates a range of precision for the measurement. This could be written as $46300$, intending $4$ significant figures. However, written this way, as mentioned in the question, we don't know whether there are $3$, $4$, or $5$ significant digits.

> If my understanding is correct, it means that say, there is a number $7878$ and it's written as $7800$ instead of $7878$ then, the number of significant digits in $7800$ is $2$ and they are $7$ and $8.$ The two zeros in $7800$ are ignored as they were used *to fill the places of unknown or discarded digits, which were $7$ and $8$ in this case.*
> **(Is this a  valid reasoning?)**

Your *understanding* seems correct. The $0$'s take place of insignificant digits that have been discarded. However, usually, a number is rounded when doing this, so if the number were $7878$, and the probable error were such that only two digits were significant, I would have written it as $7900$.

> The last two zeros in $46300$ are significant digits if $46300$ is equivalent to $46300.00$ or if, $46300$ is written in place of some number say, $46398$ (, i.e the last two digits in $46398$ which are $9$ and $8$ are discarded or is unknown and instead of it, we write, $46300$). But we aren't sure of whether any of the above two scenarios are taking place or not.
> **(Is this inference correct?)**

Given $46300$, it is not clear whether $0$, $1$, or $2$ of the $0$'s are significant. The actual value before rounding may indicate the actual number of significant digits, and how to represent this number in scientific notation, but the section "if $46300$ is equivalent to $46300.00$ or if, $46300$ is written in place of some number say, $46398$" doesn't really make sense. If you have the number $46300.00$, it apparently has $7$ significant digits, so $46300$ would be *intended* to have $5$ significant digits, but that gets lost in the representation because we are back to the original problem.

Comment: The place where you assert that $46300.00$ has $7$ significant digits is incorrect, as the $0's$ in the case, are used for "positioning" the decimal point and the zeros that are needed to fix the decimal points are insignificant. Say for example, in $0.0045, $ the digits $4$ and $5$ are the only significant digits. The $0's$ here, are simply used to fix the decimal point so, they are insignificant. You can find this rule in the OP, where I quoted a portion of the book and this case is readily handled in there.

Comment: No. The two $0$'s to the right of the decimal point are not there to fix the decimal point. They are significant. Check out [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures#Rules_to_identify_significant_figures_in_a_number); especially under **Zeros to the right of the last non-zero digit ([trailing zeros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trailing_zero)) in a number with the decimal point are significant**.